# Is there any way to dynamically allocate constant memory? CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm confused about copying arrays to constant memory.

According to [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-memory) there's at least one way to allocate constant memory and use it in order to store an array of values. And this is called static memory allocation:

```
__constant__ float constData[256];
float data[256];
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constData, data, sizeof(data));
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(data, constData, sizeof(data));
```

According to [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-memory) again we can use:

```
__device__ float* devPointer;
float* ptr;
cudaMalloc(&ptr, 256 * sizeof(float));
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(devPointer, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
```

It looks like dynamic constant memory allocation is used, but I'm not sure about it. And also no qualifier `__constant__` is used here.

So here are some questions:

1. Is this pointer stored in constant memory?
2. Is assigned (by this pointer) memory stored in constant memory too?
3. Is this pointer constant? And it's not allowed to change that pointer using device or host function. But is changing values of array prohibited or not? If changing values of array is allowed, then does it mean that constant memory is not used to store this values?

Comment: `__constant__`, like the standard C/C++ `const`, means "read-only" not "immutable". Similar to the situation in CUDA, where `__constant__` data that is read-only inside the device code can be modified by API calls in host code, a `const volatile` object can be updated by an agent outside the scope of the code where it is declared (such as an ISR, DMA transfer, or hardwae register).

Comment: @njuffa, thank you. But do we allocate memory dinamicaly when use second example of cudaMemspyToSymbol? And I've tried to find out what is the size of constant memory for compute capability 2.1. I've tried docs, but with no result. So I googled and found only [this 'NVIDIA hardware provides 64KB of constant memory'](http://cuda-programming.blogspot.ru/2013/01/what-is-constant-memory-in-cuda.html). Nothing is said for CC 2.1. Is it correct for CC 2.1 too?

Comment: Constant memory is a cache having some features. In the first snippet, you are using constant memory cache, in the second case not. In the latter case, you are simply reserving global memory space for a pointer.

Comment: I am not expert, but according to my knowledge, your pointer itself will be either in constant or device memory (depends on qualifier you used when allocated your pointer`, and memory it points to will be in constant memory.

Comment: 64 kB of constant memory are provided by the hardware. Some of it may be taken up by `__constant__` data in the CUDA math library. I am reasonably sure this is documented, check the CUDA C Programming Guide. Constant memory is a mapped portion of global memory, however access has traditionally been through a small constant cache (a few kB in size) with broadcast capability, meaning it favors uniform access (all threads in a warp read from the same address). If I recall correctly, in the Maxwell architecture the function of the constant cache has been subsumed by the read-only cache.

Comment: Constant memory size and the size of the constant cache across all GPU architectures are documented in appendix G of the CUDA C Programming Guide (my attempts to provide a direct link failed). Note that newer GPU architecture pass kernel arguments in `__constant__` memory, which will also reduce the amount left available for your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The developer can declare up to 64K of constant memory at file scope. In SM 1.0, the constant memory used by the toolchain (e.g. to hold compile-time constants) was separate and distinct from the constant memory available to developers, and I don't think this has changed since.  The driver dynamically manages switching between different views of constant memory as it launches kernels that reside in different compilation units.  Although you cannot allocate constant memory dynamically, this pattern suffices because the 64K limit is not system-wide, it only applies to compilation units.

Use the first pattern cited in your question: statically declare the constant data and update it with `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` before launching kernels that reference it.  In the second pattern, only reads of the pointer itself will go through constant memory.  Reads *using* the pointer will be serviced by the normal L1/L2 cache hierarchy.

Comment: The N-body chapter of The CUDA Handbook uses this pattern to hold 4000 bodies' data in constant memory at a time. John Stone uses a similar pattern for some of his molecular modeling kernels, when he had other uses for shared memory.  https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/blob/master/nbody/nbody_GPU_AOS_const.cuh